# Ajax Get Parent Page URI (Code Igniter)

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm loading content, forms mainly, dynamically using ajax in a Code Igniter app I'm working on. However I need get the URI segments for my DB insert and to autofill the date box on the form. Usually one would do something along the lines of:

```
$date = $this->uri->segment(3)."/".$this->uri->segment(4)."/".$this->uri->segment(5);
```

But obviously it just tries to read the address of the document being called through the ajax request, not the parent.

Any ideas how I get the parent details?

Thanks!

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            ajaxOptions: {
                error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                    $(anchor.hash).html("Unable to load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="diary-input">

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/diary_add_appt" ?>">Appointment</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/diary_add_event" ?>">Event</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/diary_add_client" ?>">New Client</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/diary_add_contact" ?>">New Contact</a></li>
        <div id="input-cell-close" class="input-cell"><a href="#"><?php echo "<img src=\"".base_url()."images/cc_close.png\" id=\"input-cell-close\" border=\"0\" alt=\"close\" />" ?></a></div>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

With jquery and jquery ui included in my document header. I'm using the jquery ui ajax tabs if you need further info: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing the Ajax request, you should send along the segments from the parent page. Like this:

In your controller:

```
$data['segments'] = $this->uri->segment(3)."/".$this->uri->segment(4)."/".$this->uri->segment(5);
```

In your view:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/diary_add_appt/{$segments}" ?>">Appointment</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/diary_add_event/{$segments}" ?>">Event</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/diary_add_client/{$segments}" ?>">New Client</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/diary_add_contact/{$segments}" ?>">New Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Captiain Tokyo! I've added some further info above, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Sorry not sure how jQuery Ajax tabs work... can also post the html for the tabs? Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer with some code? Do you get the idea? Does this work for you?

Comment: Hi Captain Tokyo, sorry I completely missed this, think I forgot to select the notifications. Thanks for the code update, that makes sense now, thanks! +1!